# Query MongoDB ObjectId using ruby driver

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I have a data structure that looks like:

```
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("533c3ce0ccf205e24fead6b8"), 
  "_class" : "test", 
  "test" : { 
        "_id" : "0502b397-4cd9-4781-bb63-70b96d799cdb", 
        "mongoTestGroups" : [  DBRef("sg", ObjectId("533c3ce0ccf205e24fead6b9")) ] 
  }, 
  "createDate" : ISODate("2014-04-02T16:37:52.175Z") 
}
```

I am having a heck of a time querying the first ObjectId. The tutorial/rdoc isn't exactly clear how to go about this. I currently have:

```
require 'json'
require 'mongo'
require 'pp'

include Mongo

db = MongoClient.new('localhost').db('mytest')
coll = db.collection('testcollection')
```

I presume it should be something like:

```
pp coll.find({_id: => { ObjectId("533c3ce0ccf205e24fead6b8")}})
```

What works fine is:

```
pp coll.count
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`BSON::ObjectId.from_string`](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/BSON/ObjectId.html#from_string-class_method) to convert your ID string to the `BSON::ObjectId` that MongoDB is expecting:

```
coll.find(_id: BSON::ObjectId.from_string('533c3ce0ccf205e24fead6b8'))
```

That `BSON::ObjectId.from_string` call is the Ruby equivalent to calling `ObjectId` in the MongoDB shell. You will quickly find that calling `BSON::ObjectId.from_string` all over the place is cumbersome so you might want to patch a `to_bson_id` into String and NilClass:

```
class String
  def to_bson_id
    BSON::ObjectId.from_string(self)
  end
end

class NilClass
  def to_bson_id
    self
  end
end
```

Then you can say things like `'533c3ce0ccf205e24fead6b9'.to_bson_id` and `some_string.to_bson_id` instead.

If you're also using Mongoid, MongoMapper, or some other ODM then you can patch `to_bson_id` into that as well; for example, with Mongoid (which uses Moped instead of MongoDB's standard interface) I do this:

```
class String
  def to_bson_id
    Moped::BSON::ObjectId(self) # This is Moped's version of BSON::ObjectId.from_string
  end
end

module Mongoid
  module Document
    def to_bson_id
      id    
    end 
  end
end

module Moped
  module BSON
    class ObjectId
      def to_bson_id
        self    
      end   
    end 
  end
end

class NilClass
  def to_bson_id
    self
  end
end
```

so that I can say:

```
str.to_bson_id
some_bson_id.to_bson_id
some_odm_object.to_bson_id
```

without caring what sort of thing I'm working with.